# How to make ANY function to repeat periodically?

Tags: periodic-functions

I have some function, say, Gauss PDF

[image]

Now I want it to repeat, say, every N units

[image]

How to transform any function this way?

I know I can sum function at each shift. But is it possible to convert argument only? I.e. apply some transform to $x$ only?

**UPDATE**

Ideally, I would like to find $g_T(t)$ such that

$\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}F(t+nT) = F(g_T(t))$

where $n \in Z$, $F$ is any function and $T$ is desired period.

I don't know if it is possible in principle, for example, endless summing may produce infinities everywhere. In this case one may introduce some weighting in lefthand side...

**UPDATE 1**

My be lefthand size should be

$\lim\limits_{k \to +\infty}\frac{1}{2k}\sum\limits_{n \in Z}F(t+nT)$

Comment: The thing you now want is impossible as stated in the equation because (for positive $F$ like your Gaussian) the left hand side takes on values larger than $F$ at any single point.

Comment: i haven't read everything here carefully, but i feel like people here have made this issue more complicated than it needs to be.  all you need is restrict $x$ to be between 0 and $T$, and define your function as $f(x+iT)=f(x)$ for all integers $i$ and an arbitrary period $T$.

Comment: ^ that should be "all you need is *to* restrict . . ."

Answer (score 12):

If you say $$p(x) = f(x\bmod N)$$

then $p$ is a periodic function with period of $N$, which has $p(x)=f(x)$ for all $x$ in  $[0, N)$.

To make $p$ and $f$ agree on an interval that is symmetric around 0, you can use $$p(x) = f\left(\left(\left(x + \frac N2\right)\bmod N\right) - \frac N2\right)$$

which is again a function that has a period of $N$, but this time $p(x) = f(x)$ for all $x$ in $\left[-\frac N2, \frac N2\right)$.

If that's not what you want, please clarify what your question is.

Comment: These solutions effectively multiply the original function be a rectangular window before summing the function at each shift. More generally, you could use some other [window function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function). For example, a smoother window would help to smooth out any discontinuities. In a way, this is a family of hybrid solutions between Suzan's and yours.

Comment: So perhaps my answer isn't really pertinent?

Comment: Oh, I think your answer is extremely pertinent! It answers the original question: "But is it possible to convert argument only?" Using a non-rectangular window would mean doing more than just changing the argument to $f$.

Comment: @ChrisCulter you could say that this means changing the argument to the "sawtooth curve" $x \pmod{n}$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, sorry, I should be clearer. I'm agreeing that MJD's answer is a positive solution to the question. My idea, on the other hand, breaks the rule by summing up a nonzero multiple of $f$ at more than one argument.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I feel like I don't understand the context of the original question very well, so I wasn't at all sure that my answer would be useful.

Comment: @MJD I was thinking about this way. But this way I cut all values outside period, i.e. if function is not localized, that periodic version will notably differ.

Answer (score 2):

A possible approach is to use a [Fourier series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) expansion of the function.

Suppose that you want to repeat the function $f(x)$ on the interval $[-L,L]$ where $L=N/2$, with $N$ as specified in the OP.

The fourier series expansion from this interval is
$$
f(x)=a_0+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)+b_n\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right),
$$
where
$$\begin{align}
a_0&=\frac1{2L}\int_{-L}^Lf(x)\,dx,\\
a_n&=\frac1{L}\int_{-L}^Lf(x)\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)\,dx,\text{ and}\\
b_n&=\frac1{L}\int_{-L}^Lf(x)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)\,dx.
\end{align}$$

Given that your function $f$ is even, we will have $b_n=0$ for all $n$.

These integals do not appear to be expressible in terms of ordinary functions (see [WolframAlpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+%28integrate+exp%28-%28x-mu%29%5E2%2F%282sigma%5E2%29%2BI%2an%2api%2ax%2FL%29+for+x%3D-L+to+L%29&x=0&y=0)). Thus, for this approach, the integrals have to be numerically approximated, which could cause further numerical problems.